# Random ssl handshake failure when pulling file from Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, handshake

I have a specific fetch request in my node app which just pulls a json file from my S3 bucket and stores the content within the state of my app.

The fetch request works 99% of the time but for some reason about every 4 or 5 days I get a notification saying the app has crashed and when I investigate the reason is always because of this `ssl handshake failure`.

I am trying to figure out why this is happening as well as a fix to prevent this in future cases.

The fetch request looks like the following and is called everything someone new visits the site, Once the request has been made and the json is now in the app's state, the request is no longer called.

```
function grabPreParsedContentFromS3 (prefix, callback) {
   fetch(`https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/${prefix}.json`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => callback(res[prefix]))
     .catch(e => console.log('Error fetching data from s3: ', e))

 }
```

When this error happens the `.catch` method with get thrown and returns the following error message:

```
Error fetching data from s3:  {
   FetchError: request to https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/my-bucket/services.json failed,
   reason: write EPROTO 139797093521280:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_pkt.c:659:
   ...
 }
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of issue before or has any idea why this might be happening? Currently I am wondering if maybe there is a limit to the amount of S3 request i can make at one time which is causing it to fail? But the site isn't super popular either to be request a huge portion of fetches.

Comment: Does retrying with the same params work? Couldn’t you just update the retry policy to handle this transient error in that case? If the same params always causes it, then that would be a case for AWS support

Comment: Yeah so what will be happening is it will crash the node app, I then will restart the app and then everything works fine again. I have no problems with that request anymore @Krease

Comment: @BradyEdgar did you solve the issue?